# Check both if empty or if contains value in Javascript object (ES2015)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out the best and most clean/concise way to check first if an object even has any values, and if so, if one of those values is `71`.

In essence, if the object is `empty` then the function should return `true`. Also if the function isn't `empty` but contains `71` as one of the values (they're numerically indexed) then it should be true. Everything else false.

What I have at the moment works but seems kinda messy and lengthy:

`facets` is the object

```
if (Object.keys(facets).length === 0) {
  if (facets[index] == 71) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `return Object.keys(facets).length == 0 || facets[index] === 71;` ?

Comment: If they are numerically indexed why not use simple array?

Comment: Do you always know the index that should contain 71?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index, check if the index contains the value, and if not, check if it's empty:

```js
const has = (obj, index, value) => obj[index] === 71 || !Object.keys(obj).length;

const index = 2;
const value = 71;

console.log('empty: ', has({}, index, value));
console.log('contains 71: ', has({ 1: 13}, index, value));
console.log('contains 71: ', has({ 1: 13, 2: 71 }, index, value));
```

---

If you don't know the index, you can use `Object#keys` to extract the keys, check if length is 0 (`!values.length`), and if not use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to see the object contains the request value:

```js
const facets = { 1: 0, 2: 71 };

const has = (obj, value) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return !keys.length || keys.findIndex((key) => obj[key] === value) !== -1;
}

const value = 71;

console.log('empty: ', has({}, value));
console.log('contains 71: ', has({ 1: 13}, value));
console.log('contains 71: ', has({ 1: 13, 2: 71 }, value));
```

---

Another option when the index is unknown is to use [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

**Note**: `Object#values` is not part of ECMAScript2015 (ES6), but a draft in ECMAScript2017, and is supported only by Chrome and Firefox.

Use `Object#values` to extract the values, check if length is 0 (`!values.length`), and if not use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see if `values` contain the request value.

```js
const facets = { 1: 0, 2: 71 };

const has = (obj, value) => {
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  return !values.length || values.includes(value);
}

const value = 71;

console.log('empty: ', has({}, value));
console.log('contains 71: ', has({ 1: 13}, value));
console.log('contains 71: ', has({ 1: 13, 2: 71 }, value));
```

Comment: `Object.values` isn't ES6

Answer (score 0):

> In essence, if the object is empty then the function should return true. Also if the function isn't empty but contains 71 as one of the values (they're numerically indexed) then it should be true. Everything else false.

It is

```
return !Object.keys(facets).length || facets[index] == 71;
```

There's no need to explicitly return `true` or `false` because comparison and logical operators result in boolean value.